# Matched object type miss when expression case. Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, instanceof

It just blew my mind. So maybe someone was faced with such a problem. I try to use a new approach for Retrofit with statements. The problem is that even with a matched instance of the result else block applies. How can it be?

```
override fun invoke(result: GraphCallResult<QueryRoot>) {
        when(result) {
            is GraphCallResult.Success -> {
                 collections.postValue(Converter.convertCollections(result.response.data?.collections))
                 loading.postValue(false)
            }
            is GraphCallResult.Failure -> {
                 loading.postValue(false)
            }
            else -> {
                 loading.postValue(false)
            }
        }    
}
```

And here is a screenshot from debugging process.
[image]

Here is a GraphCallResult implementation.

```
sealed class GraphCallResult<out T : AbstractResponse<out T>> {
    /**
     * `GraphQL` operation result returned for success execution, with the typed operation response that will contain fields that match
     * exactly the fields requested.
     */
    class Success<T : AbstractResponse<T>>(val response: GraphResponse<T>) : GraphCallResult<T>()

    /**
     * `GraphQL` operation result returned for failed execution, with the error caused this call to fail.
     *
     * @see GraphError
     */
    class Failure(val error: GraphError) : GraphCallResult<Nothing>()
}
```

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please show how `GraphCallResult.Success` is implemented?

Comment: @Demigod sure. I'm so surprised. Because this approach is represented in Shopify's official sample projects. And as I see it suppose to work! But here we are...

Comment: This is so strange. The only thing I can think of is generics. Maybe it has something to do with it. Cause, your when accepts `GraphCallResult<QueryRoot>` and, maybe, the `GraphCallResult.Success` has other types? Anyway, something to check)